# Accessing resources from a service launched at boot

Tags: java, android, service, resources

At boot, I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which launches a `Service`. In this `Service`, I trigger a `Notification`, and I want the text of the `Notification` to be retrieved from the `Activity` which will be launched when the user clicks the `Notification` (through it's resources).

The `BroadcastRecevier`, the `Service` and the `Activity` are all bundled in the same package.

The question is : how can I retrieve the `Activity`'s resources from the `Service` as I don't have any handler for my `Activity` in it? And I can't have one since the `Service` is launched before the `Activity`.

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities don't have resources. *Applications* have resources. Your service would access your application's resources in the same way anything else does (e.g., via calls to `getString()`, or `getResources()).